# How can i surround double quotes to the hex came from the file

Tags: php, hex

I have file named test.log,inside of it I have many hex lines,but the problem is that when I am trying to convert to

```
hex2bin($hex)
```

I receive this warning

```
Warning: hex2bin(): Hexadecimal input string must have an even length
```

but I will do manually example

$hex = "hexhere";

```
hex2bin($hex)
```

It works fine.because I surround it with doublquotes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: made a answer!)

Answer (score 0):

> A warning is thrown if the input string is of odd length. In PHP
>   5.4.0 the string was silently accepted, but the last byte was truncated.

As you can see your length in the file is odd! So i think your using a php version 5.4 or higher! (check the length in your file)

Answer (score -1):

hex2bin — Decodes a hexadecimally encoded binary string,  doc： http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

Comment: That's not a answer to OP's question!